# Как проверить, что сообщение отправил не мой бот? Discord.net c#

Tags: c#, discord

Код который вроде как должен работать, но что-то не так.

```
if (msg.Author.IsBot & msg.Author.Id != айди моего бота)
{
    await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync(msg.Interaction);
}
```

Мой бот должен отвечать на сообщение любого другого бота, кроме себя, но он отвечает так же и на свое сообщение, что приводит к бесконечному отправлению сообщения пока я полностью его не выключу.

Comment: Как минимум вместо & должно быть &&

Comment: Я пробовал так делать, результат такой же.

Comment: Попробуй вывести в консоль msg.Author.Id и посмотреть, совпадает ли он с айди бота. может они все же разные.

Comment: Такая же ситуация(

Comment: Используйте отладку, ставьте точки останова, выполняйте код пошагово, смотрите значения переменных в процессе пошагового выполнения.

Comment: Проблема этого в том, что отладка не дает посмотреть, что происходит в коде, она работает до того как откроется консоль с логами бота, дальше она отключается.

Comment: Так ставьте точку останова на нужном участке кода.